# Datatables filter numbers greater than

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using [datables](https://datatables.net/), I need to filter particular column whose values are greater than 50 , I tried below code , but nothing happens

```
oTable.api().column( 10 )
  .data()
  .filter( function ( value, index ) {
     var htmlObject = $(value);
     var ball = htmlObject.text();
     return parseInt(ball) > 50 ? true : false;
   })
  .draw();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check any number greater than 5 then you can write ternary conditional with the hidden column in dataTable.
Using filter add MORETHAN5RECORD as a value in the select dropdown to filter greater than 5 records.

```js
Here is the Code :
var table = $('#record_table').DataTable({});
$('.FILTERCLASS').on('keyup change', function () {
  buildFilters(table,this);
}); 
 
function buildFilters(table, element){     
    var type = $(element).data('type'),
        col = $(element).data('col'),
        id = $(element).id;   
      table
          .column( col )
          .search( element.value )
          .draw();
    }
```

```html
 <td><?php 
echo (($row['xyz'] >= 5) ? $val['xyz']."(MORETHAN5RECORD)" : $val['xyz']); ?> </td>
```

Answer (score 4):

"Nothing happens" because nothing is expected to happen. [`filter()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()) should be used to create internal datasets or extract subsets of data - if you want to filter the rows in the table you should use a [custom filter](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html). It could look like this :

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
  return data[10] > 50 //type conversion is not necessary
})
```

This works as a "master" filter *before* `.search()` (and other filters). If you want to remove the filter you can use `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop()`. So

1. `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push( filter function )`
2. `table.draw()`
3. `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop()`